# Oracle: DECODE on BLOB column

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, blob

I am trying to use DECODE on the column of type BLOB. Here is what I did:

```
update TOTAL 
set DATA = decode (DATA, null, null, XMLSERIALIZE (CONTENT XMLTYPE('<myxml>' || DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('X', 200) || '</myxml>') as blob));
```

I am getting the following error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got BLOB
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
```

If I use `where DATA is not null`Instead of decode, it is running fine. Could you help me fix this? Thanks in advance. P.S: I am using `DECODE` instead of `NVL2` or `WHERE` clause, just to be consistent with the rest of the script

Answer (score 0):

you can try `case when`  instead of `decode`

### try this.

```
case when DATA is null then null
else  XMLSERIALIZE (CONTENT XMLTYPE('<myxml>' || DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('X', 200) || '</myxml>') as blob)
end
```